# Sorting array ascending with duplicates at the end also sorted ascending

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to sort a array in place like [3,2,1,2,4,5,3] so that it is in sorted order ascending but with all duplicates grouped at the end in sorted order. So the result for the array would be [1,4,5,2,2,3,3]. How can I do this without using python built in sort()?

Comment: Can you explain the in-place requirement?  This seems like it's going to require at least some sort of auxiliary data structure that is potentially as large as the array.

Comment: By in place I mean insert into the original array by using multiple pointers and/or a temp variable

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `key` argument as a tuple (whether value repeats, value itself):

```
sort(l, key=lambda v: (l.count(v) > 1, v))
```

UPD: This is fine for smaller lists. However, as @Stef mentioned in the comment, this solution has a quadratic complexity while you can do it in N * log(N):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(l)
sort(l, key=lambda x: (c[x] > 1, x))
```

Comment: This counts the duplicates multiple times, resulting in a quadratic complexity. An alternative is: `from collections import Counter; c = Counter(l); sort(l, key=lambda x: (c[x] > 1, x))`

Comment: @Stef, thanks, added your solution and explanation.

Comment: It doesn't have an N^2 log(N) complexity. Just N^2. `sort` calls the `key` function only once per item in the list, before sorting.

Comment: @Stef Today I learned. Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two phases.

1. Just sort the array in-place with your favorite in-place sorting algorithm
2. Scanning sorted array right to left, find the first `DU` subarray (where `D` is a bunch of duplicate values, and `U` is a tail of unique elements). Make it into `UD`. Keep going.

The second phase completes in `O(n)`.